# Transparent Wrapper Components in Angular 6+

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js

One of the brilliant features in `Vue.js` is the ability to assign new attributes to a specific element in the template. known as [Transparent Wrapper Components](https://zendev.com/2018/05/31/transparent-wrapper-components-in-vue.html)

[image]

In this sample, I can send all existing HTML attributes to a specific element. (in here with v-bind="$attrs" for input)

How to assign all existing HTML attributes to a specific element of a template without coping as binding property in Angular 6+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this out of the box, and I think that is by design.

Its kind of ugly but I got similar functionality writing a `BindAttrsDirective` here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bind-attrs

Note: won't support SSR